# table with many columns

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have some questions about the below table:

1. If I omit the margins, the table will completely get disordered.
2. I want to have the two 4 columns in the middle to have a slight distance with each other but the \cmidrule is not working properly
3. as you can see at the right side of the table the data have come out of the table.

I will be more than grateful if you kindly help me solve the problems.

```
\documentclass{article} [8pt]
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mhchem} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[htb]
  \label{tbl:stats-and-correlations}

  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{8}{c}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Panel A:}} 
     & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Panel B:}}  \\ \cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-9}

               & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $}
               & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} \\ [0.5ex]
               & (\si{\angstrom})
               & (\si{\angstrom})
               & (\si{\angstrom})
               & (\si{\angstrom})
               & (\si{\angstrom})
               & (\si{\angstrom})
               & (\si{\angstrom})
               & (\si{\angstrom}) \\
               \hline
    Variable~1 &    0.78 &    0.37 &    0.48 &    0.10 &    0.13 &    0.58 &    0.41 &    0.10\\
    Variable~2 &    0.46 &    0.86 &    0.96 &    0.44 &    0.15 &    0.56 &    0.31 &    0.10\\
    Variable~3 &    0.03 &    0.75 &    0.11 &    0.44 &    0.71 &    0.06 &    0.26 &    0.10\\
    Variable~4 &    0.21 &    0.25 &    0.38 &    0.88 &    0.24 &    0.52 &    0.46 &    0.10\\
    Variable~5 &    0.20 &    0.93 &    0.54 &    0.96 &    0.55 &    0.82 &    0.62 &    0.10\\
    Variable~6 &    0.67 &    0.85 &    0.74 &    0.99 &    0.27 &    0.48 &    0.85 &    0.10\\
    Variable~7 &    0.82 &    0.89 &    0.68 &    0.06 &    0.02 &    0.30 &    0.10 &    0.10\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}


\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\cmidrule(lr){2-5}` to shorten the rule on either side (left, right).

Comment: Btw: Those `cmidrule` are working properly and as documented. You specifically need to trim thos using the optional argument.

Comment: The rules typeset by `booktabs` are limited to the textwidth. You table is just toooo huge. Consider to put it landscape.

Comment: The same reason lets the bit stand out to the right a bit. Use \geometry{showframe}` to verify.

Comment: What is that `[8pt]` doing there after the `\documentclass`? You could add a `\small` after `\begin{table*}` to make the table a bit smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Given that all of your column headers are the same, and the `d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}}` is what is causing the columns to be so wide, I suggest combining all of the column labels. Incorporating the triming suggestions of @Johannes_B from the comments above you can get:

[image]

by writing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[htb]
  \label{tbl:stats-and-correlations}

  \begin{tabular}{l*{4}l*4{c}}
    \toprule
    \
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Panel A:}}
     & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Panel B:}}  \\ \cmidrule(r){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
    &\multicolumn {4}{c}{$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $ (\si{\angstrom})}
     &\multicolumn {4}{c}{$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $ (\si{\angstrom})} \\[0.8ex]
               \hline
    Variable~1 &    0.78 &    0.37 &    0.48 &    0.10 &    0.13 &    0.58 &    0.41 &    0.10\\
    Variable~2 &    0.46 &    0.86 &    0.96 &    0.44 &    0.15 &    0.56 &    0.31 &    0.10\\
    Variable~3 &    0.03 &    0.75 &    0.11 &    0.44 &    0.71 &    0.06 &    0.26 &    0.10\\
    Variable~4 &    0.21 &    0.25 &    0.38 &    0.88 &    0.24 &    0.52 &    0.46 &    0.10\\
    Variable~5 &    0.20 &    0.93 &    0.54 &    0.96 &    0.55 &    0.82 &    0.62 &    0.10\\
    Variable~6 &    0.67 &    0.85 &    0.74 &    0.99 &    0.27 &    0.48 &    0.85 &    0.10\\
    Variable~7 &    0.82 &    0.89 &    0.68 &    0.06 &    0.02 &    0.30 &    0.10 &    0.10\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should remove the `[8pt]` option in the first line because it's misplaced (it should come before, not after, `{article}`) and - more importantly - because the `article` document class doesn't even recognize `[8pt]` as an option.

Comment: @Mico Thanks. Done. Hadn't looked at the preamble at all...

Comment: What is `tabularx` supposed to do, since you're not using `X` columns?

Comment: @egreg I agree, it's unnecessary.

Comment: The columns are not the same in the title. I just put the "d" parameters as samples here.

Comment: @sryzdn Can you shorten your real column headings -- or rotate them?

Comment: @Andrew Unfortunately no. I am preparing this table for a paper I am going to submit. I have seen wider tables done with "table*" and "ruledtabular". But I can't use ruledtabular here.

Comment: @sryzdn What do you mean by *wider*? You are limited by the pagewidth (not taking margins into account).

Comment: @Johannes_B yes, the page width is a limit. But, I have seen tables with 10 columns in "revtex" package that were fitting into half of the whole page width. I want to solve the problem of the right side of the table that the data are shifting out of the table. I will be thankful if someone help me with that.

Answer (score 2):

Your table is wider then the available `\linewidth` and the `tabularx` is used without any `X` column.

One possibility to get  the table right is using `\small` and defining the first column as an `X` column:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[htb]
  \label{tbl:stats-and-correlations}
  \small\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X*{8}{c}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Panel A:}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Panel B:}}\\ \cmidrule(r){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
    & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} 
    & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} \\ [0.5ex]
    & (\si{\angstrom}) & (\si{\angstrom}) & (\si{\angstrom}) & (\si{\angstrom}) & (\si{\angstrom}) & (\si{\angstrom}) & (\si{\angstrom}) & (\si{\angstrom}) \\
    \midrule
    Variable~1 &    0.78 &    0.37 &    0.48 &    0.10 &    0.13 &    0.58 &    0.41 &    0.10\\
    Variable~2 &    0.46 &    0.86 &    0.96 &    0.44 &    0.15 &    0.56 &    0.31 &    0.10\\
    Variable~3 &    0.03 &    0.75 &    0.11 &    0.44 &    0.71 &    0.06 &    0.26 &    0.10\\
    Variable~4 &    0.21 &    0.25 &    0.38 &    0.88 &    0.24 &    0.52 &    0.46 &    0.10\\
    Variable~5 &    0.20 &    0.93 &    0.54 &    0.96 &    0.55 &    0.82 &    0.62 &    0.10\\
    Variable~6 &    0.67 &    0.85 &    0.74 &    0.99 &    0.27 &    0.48 &    0.85 &    0.10\\
    Variable~7 &    0.82 &    0.89 &    0.68 &    0.06 &    0.02 &    0.30 &    0.10 &    0.10\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Note that I have changed `\hline` to `\midrule`.

---

Another possibility is  using `\small` together with `tabular*` and @{\extracolsep{\fill}} behind the first column definition.

```
\small\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{8}{c}}
...
\end{tabular*}
```

will stretch all columns so that the width of the table fits `\linewidth`.

[image]

---

Or you can use `\resizebox` from the `graphics` bundle if your table width differs not so much from line width.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}% loads also graphicx
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[htb]
  \label{tbl:stats-and-correlations}
  \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{l*{8}{c}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Panel A:}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Panel B:}}\\ \cmidrule(r){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
    & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} 
    & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} & {$d_{(\ce{O1}-\ce{Mg_{(Zn)}})} $} \\ [0.5ex]
    & (\si{\angstrom}) & (\si{\angstrom}) & (\si{\angstrom}) & (\si{\angstrom}) & (\si{\angstrom}) & (\si{\angstrom}) & (\si{\angstrom}) & (\si{\angstrom}) \\
    \midrule
    Variable~1 &    0.78 &    0.37 &    0.48 &    0.10 &    0.13 &    0.58 &    0.41 &    0.10\\
    Variable~2 &    0.46 &    0.86 &    0.96 &    0.44 &    0.15 &    0.56 &    0.31 &    0.10\\
    Variable~3 &    0.03 &    0.75 &    0.11 &    0.44 &    0.71 &    0.06 &    0.26 &    0.10\\
    Variable~4 &    0.21 &    0.25 &    0.38 &    0.88 &    0.24 &    0.52 &    0.46 &    0.10\\
    Variable~5 &    0.20 &    0.93 &    0.54 &    0.96 &    0.55 &    0.82 &    0.62 &    0.10\\
    Variable~6 &    0.67 &    0.85 &    0.74 &    0.99 &    0.27 &    0.48 &    0.85 &    0.10\\
    Variable~7 &    0.82 &    0.89 &    0.68 &    0.06 &    0.02 &    0.30 &    0.10 &    0.10\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

---

Additionally you can save space by removing the left `\tabcolsep` of the first column and the right `\tablcolsep` of the last column: add `@{}` at the begin and the end of the column definitions. That means for the last example

```
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{8}{c}@{}}
...
\end{tabular}}
```

[image]